# SQL trouble with insert in if statement

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS kund2orderNew;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE kund2orderNew(kundId2 INT)
BEGIN
IF kundId2 <> (SELECT kundId FROM kund2order) THEN
    INSERT INTO kundOrder VALUES ();
    INSERT INTO kund2order VALUES (kundId2, (SELECT id FROM kundOrder)); 
END IF;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Alright am I doing something wrong here? What im trying to do is to check if kundId is in  the kund2order, if its not then what I want to do is create a new row in the kundOrder table that just uses the default values and then take the recently created id from that row in the  kundOrder and put it inside the new row in  kund2order (together with kundId).

For some reason it just gives me (node:18328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'kundId' cannot be null

I am a bit confused as to what the problem is, both tables are empty after I have called this procedure. Is the problem my if statement or is it something else?

Comment: Besides other problems, your first `IF` has the obvious potential problem that the subquery on the RHS might return more than one record.  Maybe you intended to use `WHERE NOT IN ...`, but in any case, it would help your question to better explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: If kundId2 does not match any kundId in the kund2order table I want to execute the below Insert statements. If it does match something then I want nothing to happen

Comment: That's not how you check if `kundid2` is in the table.

Comment: @Barmar How would I do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct way to check if an ID is already in the table. When you use a `SELECT` query as an expression, it has to return just one row. You can use:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kund2Order WHERE kundId = kundId2) THEN
```

And if you want to insert the auto-increment of the row that was just inserted into `kundOrder`, you should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
INSERT INTO kund2order VALUES (kundId2, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```